# I have an RPM, and want to create an online repo

Tags: yum, rpm, repository

I have an rpm, a specific version of Spotify for Fedora, that is publicly available in a repository[1]. What can I do so that I will create a repository of mine(preferably in github) that will have this specific version of Spotify (this rpm package), so that if this repository[1] gets an updated version, I'll have a repository of mine with the old version.

Thanks

[1] http://negativo17.org/spotify-client/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A yum repo is essentially a file repository either local, ftp or http. Since you have a remote repository with repo data you can use the `yum utils` package on Fedora to clone the repo.

First install the needed packages to synchronize and manage repository metadata.

```
yum install yum-utils
```

Next subscribe the machine that will host your repo to the Fedora Spotitify repo.

```
yum-config-manager --add-repo=http://negativo17.org/repos/fedora-spotify.repo
```

Now create a path where you will host you repo mirror. I use `/opt/repo` as an example.

```
mkdir /opt/repo
cd /opt/repo
```

Mirror the repository for Spotify (note: if you arch on the host is different from your client you may need to modify this command to download specific arch versions)

```
reposync -r epel-spotify -n
```

This will create a mirror of the Spotify repo in `/opt/repo/epel-spotify`. You can then schedule the reposync command nightly or weekly and it will only download new packages. Additionally, you could configure Apache, lighttpd or nginx (or any other http or ftp server) to host the mirror location.

Finally, you can configure your local machine to use the mirror on the local filesystem, configure the local filesystem to be mounted by other clients on your network or clients can use ftp or http to retrieve packages after setting up a repo configuration file similar to one below.

cat /etc/yum.repos.d/spotify-local.repo

```
# file /etc/yum.repos.d/spotify-local.repo
[spotify-local]
name=My Personal Local Yum Repo
baseurl=file:///opt/repo/epel-spotify/
enabled=0
```

cat /etc/yum.repos.d/spotify-http.repo

```
# http /etc/yum.repos.d/spotify-http.repo
[spotify-http]
name=My Http Spotify Yum Repo
baseurl=http://yumserver.example.com/epel-spotify
enabled=0
```

cat /etc/yum.repos.d/spotify-ftp.repo

```
# ftp /etc/yum.repos.d/spotify-ftp.repo
[spotify-ftp]
name=My FTP Spotify Yum Repo
baseurl=ftp://yumserver.example.com/epel-spotify
enabled=0
```

Once one of these repo configurations is installed on a client (and http or ftp is running properly) you simply need to enable the repo and look for packages.

```
yum --enablerepo=spotify-local search spotify
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the most offical way to do this is [Copr](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Category:Copr), which acts in a similar way to Ubuntu's PPAs. Repos can be added to yum via a repo file - for example, [this copr](https://copr.fedoraproject.org/coprs/churchyard/chromium-russianfedora/) provides a updated version of Chromium, which can be added in various ways:
YUM repo file (@ `/etc/yum.repos.d/churchyard-chromium-russianfedora-fedora-21.repo` - provided by RPM on the page):

```
[churchyard-chromium-russianfedora]
name=Copr repo for chromium-russianfedora owned by churchyard
baseurl=https://copr-be.cloud.fedoraproject.org/results/churchyard/chromium-russianfedora/fedora-$releasever-$basearch/
skip_if_unavailable=True
gpgcheck=0
enabled=0
#priority=99
```

or, using DNF (default Fedora 22+ I think):

```
dnf copr enable churchyard/chromium-russianfedora
```

However, it may be restricted to having certain software licenses and stuff, and you might need jump through some hoops to get it set properly. So a alternate method would be to do what your linked site seems to be doing, and create a repo file pointing to a server with the appropriate RPMs - it uses [this repo file](http://negativo17.org/repos/fedora-spotify.repo), and points to http://negativo17.org/repos/spotify/... with a directory structure to house all the needed RPMs. If you did create your own public repo, you will have to remove/change the GPG key stuff, change the package version and change-log appropriately, and it would be nice if you got permission from the author of the project as well (on the page the author says they have means of contact in the package's changelog).

If you just want to have a version that you can install if you need to, YUM accepts URLs, so you should be able to to install it with needing to set up a repo - e.g. for a laptop with CentOS, I have can do this to install a version of `kmod-wl` it needs:

```
sudo yum install https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/yu8cvxaj9u269il/kmod-wl-6_30_223_248-2.el7.local.x86_64.rpm
```

yum then downloads and checks the package, and installs it if it needs to (DNF may do the same, not a clue)